# Downloading Binary content (images) from on-premises server using Azure Data Factory "Rest" Dataset

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

We have this Rest based web-wervice hosted on-premises.

We are using Azure Data Factory with Integration-Runtime configure on-premises on a server.

We are getting urls of images (all different but hosted on same server).
Is it possible to  download these images from these rest-endpoints (hosted in on-premises server) using ADF?

Comment: Hi Prashant, Is it possible to share more details on usage of Azure data factory with Integration-runtime as a solution for this requirement. I am trying to understand if there is any compelling reason for choice of ADF in this scenario. Thanks

Comment: Hi Alok, we already have integration runtime configured to fetch other relational data from on-premise servers. Hence if this can be achieved by ADF's REST activities would make things simpler. But if its not feasible we need to clearly call it out  and propose alternatives.

Comment: As Azure Data factory offers three types of Integration Runtime, i.e. Azure, Self-Hosted and Azure-SSIS, please share which type is currently configured.

Comment: We are using self-hosted IR to access on-premis data sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already set up Self-hosted IR on your machine,i think you could use Copy Activity to transfer binary contents into Azure Service(e.g Azure Blob Storage)

Base on this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-binary),Binary format is supported for the REST connectors and Blob Storage connectors:

[image]

Comment: Bang-On!!!
Thanks Jay, as per the document using HTTP Binary Dataset in a copy activity was all i needed.
Thank you